# Knime: Time Series

Tags: time-series, knime

I have a list of time series and I have extracted the time and date field for my calculation. I would Like to insert all the missing dates that fall under two row,Like the one in the screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLxXW.png).

P.S. I do not have a code to add here.

Update : I have tried to add a lag column to get the next time and then a java script to find the number of interval. Now I have a number of columns to be inserted but I am finding it difficult to insert the rows and also is there any other efficient way than this?

Update 2:

I have tried generating time series like

Date and time   Group

2012-02-24      0

2012-02-24      1

2012-02-24      2

2012-02-24      3

2012-02-25      0

2012-02-25      1

2012-02-25      2

2012-02-25      3

And I have a time series like

Date and time   Group

24.2.2012        1

24.2.2012        2

24.2.2012        3

25.2.2012        0

25.2.2012        1

25.2.2012        2

25.2.2012        3

May i know how to merge them in knime to achieve

Date and time   Group

2012-02-24      Null

2012-02-24      1

2012-02-24      2

2012-02-24      3

2012-02-25      0

2012-02-25      1

2012-02-25      2

2012-02-25      3

Comment: May I please know the reason behind the down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to produce it by creating a unique date series and then  using Join node and then sorting it based on Date. Thank you.